# Anko version dependencies (com.android.support.support-v4:27.1.1)

Tags: anko

I am trying to migrate my app to targeting android sdk 28.

I think I am getting tripped up by the Anko dependency on support 27.1.1 which occurs [here](https://github.com/Kotlin/anko/blob/master/build.gradle)

I am failing with conflicting dependencies on com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.1 and com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:28.0.0

If I try to match Anko's use of 27.1.1, then my build complains that I should not use a support version lower than my target version.

So I am puzzled at where to go from here. Just not target sdk28 if I am using Anko :-( ?

Answer (score 1):

This was bugging me as well. First I made sure the Android support libraries were up-to-date and added each of these from the Android support libraries packages https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/packages

Then added the following to the end of build.gradle in the app:

```
configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { DependencyResolveDetails details ->
        def requested = details.requested
        if (requested.group == 'com.android.support') {
            if (!requested.name.startsWith("multidex")) {
                details.useVersion '28.0.0'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Hope this works for you!